# MongoDB check the time of document log

Tags: mongodb, datetime, time

I have a collection which stores a array of strings as a part of document and _id , is there a possibility that I can check the timestamp of any of the document which is logged.
the document structure is:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1370891970), "k" : [ "argos","test"]}
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

-V

Comment: where is the timestamp stored?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your document structure, then there is no way to check it. None of your fields contains this information and you also overwrite your `_id` field.